# Difference approach when persisting data

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject, nscoding

I need to fetch the data of merchant and display it into TableView, i also want to persist the data, but I'm still confused on what approach should I use.
Just also want to ask the difference between this two approach, especially their advantages.

This one:

```
class Merchant: NSObject {
  var merchantID : NSNumber?
  var merchantName :  String?
  var merchantaddress :  String?
  var contact_person : String?
  var mobile_number : NSNumber?

  var merchantImage :  String?

  var products : Product?

init?(merchantID: NSNumber, merchantName: String, merchantAddress: String, contactPerson: String, mobileNumber: NSNumber, merchantImage: String, products: Product){

    self.merchantID = merchantID
    self.merchantName = merchantName
    self.merchantaddress = merchantAddress
    self.contact_person = contactPerson
    self.mobile_number = mobileNumber
    self.merchantImage = merchantImage

    self.products = products

    super.init()
}
```

}

and this one:

```
class Merchant: NSObject, NSCoding {
  var merchantID : NSNumber?
  var merchantName :  String?
  var merchantAddress :  String?
  var contactPerson : String?
  var mobileNumber : NSNumber?

  var merchantImage :  String?

  var products : Product?

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("merchant")

// MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {

    static let merchantIDKey = "merchant_id"
    static let merchantNameKey = "merchant_name"
    static let merchantaddressKey = "merchant_address"
    static let merchant_contpersonKey = "contact_person"
    static let merchantmobile_numberkey = "mobile_number"

    static let merchantImageKey = "merchant_image"

    static let productKey = "persons"

}

init?(merchantID: NSNumber, merchantName: String, merchantAddress: String, contactPerson: String, mobileNumber: NSNumber, merchantImage: String, products: Product){

    self.merchantID = merchantID
    self.merchantName = merchantName
    self.merchantAddress = merchantAddress
    self.contactPerson = contactPerson
    self.mobileNumber = mobileNumber
    self.merchantImage = merchantImage

    self.products = products

    super.init()
}


// MARK: NSCoding

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encode(merchantID, forKey: PropertyKey.merchantIDKey)
    aCoder.encode(merchantName, forKey: PropertyKey.merchantNameKey)
    aCoder.encode(merchantAddress, forKey: PropertyKey.merchantaddressKey)
    aCoder.encode(contactPerson, forKey: PropertyKey.merchant_contpersonKey)
    aCoder.encode(mobileNumber, forKey: PropertyKey.merchantmobile_numberkey)

    aCoder.encode(merchantImage, forKey: PropertyKey.merchantImageKey)
    aCoder.encode(products, forKey: PropertyKey.productKey)

}


required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let merchantid = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.merchantIDKey) as! NSNumber
    let merchantname = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.merchantNameKey) as! String
    let merchantaddress = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.merchantaddressKey) as! String
    let contactperson = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.merchant_contpersonKey) as! String

    let mobilenumber = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.merchantmobile_numberkey) as! NSNumber
    let merchantimage = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.merchantImageKey) as! String

     let product = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.productKey) as! Product

    // Must call designated initializer.

    self.init(merchantID: merchantid, merchantName: merchantname, merchantAddress: merchantaddress, contactPerson : contactperson, mobileNumber: mobilenumber, merchantImage: merchantimage, products: product)
}


@discardableResult func loadSender() -> [Merchant]? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Merchant.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Merchant]
}
```

}

I am a beginner in Swift
Thank you

Comment: Using the first method, you're not saving the data to disk. In the second method, I believe you are fetching the data from the disk. For more info for saving the data using NSCoding, I suggest you to check the tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data